# What is the difference between the type of those two files?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to test correlation power analysis attack with two different files of ciphertexts: The first file Ciphertexts.mat was already converted from numpy to matlab by using this line of codes:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np

tab_Obs = np.load('C:\\Users\\My_Test_Traces\\Ciphertexts.npy')
scipy.io.savemat('C:\\Users\\My_Test_Traces\\Ciphertexts.mat', {
 "tab_Obs":tab_Obs}
)
```

The result is:

```
load 'C:/Users/cpa/data/Ciphertexts.mat';
  S =
     {
       ciph_dec =

            163   20   11  228    7   53  249  241  134   90  166  177  179   43   86  103
             35   22  125  217   16   82  174  101  197  242  118   33  214  232   86  162
             77  116   29  212   76    7  155   18  255  101  126   86  235  155   46   11
             ...........
     }
```

The second file is parsed_cipher_0cm.mat:

```
load 'C:/Users/cpa/data/parsed_cipher_0cm.mat'; 


  S =
        {
          ciph_dec =

              67    70   185   254    55    71    60   118   165    27   247   120    31   106   154    24
              24    51   124    37   190   187   208    55    32   224   134   214    49   173   224   209
             192    86   229    54    24   216    91     9   136   132   131    82    44   170   234    33
             .......
       }
```

At first, I think that I have the same two files with the same type, after that, when I try to execute the second file gives me the best solution but the execution via the second file gives me this result:

```
error: binary operator `*' not implemented for `int32 matrix' by `matrix' operations
error: evaluating binary operator `*' near line 57, column 10
```

My error is the type of the first file, the error is in the calculation of the h1. 
I try by this code in matlab:

```
load 'C:/Users/cpa/data/Ciphertexts.mat'; 
%load 'C:/Users/cpa/data/parsed_cipher_0cm.mat';
% truncate measurements
n_measures = 999
tab_Obs = tab_Obs(1:n_measures,:);
ciph_dec = ciph_dec(1:n_measures,:);
K=0:255;
disp (length(K));
Y_i = ciph_dec(:,sbox_n)
F = ones(1,length(K))
sbox_n = 2
disp (size(Y_i))
disp (size(F))
h1=(Y_i*ones(1,length(K)))
disp (size(h1))
```

I did this test to know the type of each file:
I find that:

```
Ciphertexts.mat---------> type: int32
parsed_cipher_0cm.mat---> type: float64
```

I need to have the file Ciphertexts.mat' s type= float64, how to resolve the problem please?

Comment: What is the [`class()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) of `ciph_dec` in each file? MATLAB is not fond of matrix multiplication of integer types.

Comment: could you take a look at the edited question please!

Comment: Do you need to use integers?

Comment: No I need as a float64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply converting to double - `ciph_dec = double(ciph_dec)`. Matlab prefers those and as long as you are within int32, double has all these numbers, so you won't be losing precision.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB does not generally allow for matrix multiplication involving integer data types unless one of the operands is a scalar. We can see this with a simple example:

```
ones(2, 'int8')*ones(2, 'int8')
```

Which throws an error:

```
Error using  * 
MTIMES is not fully supported for integer classes. At least one input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.
```

This likely for [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) safety, though there may be other reasons I'm not familiar with. Though the error messages are not exact, the issue is presumably related.

The immediate MATLAB fix is to cast `ciph_dec` as a [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), which should resolve the multiplication issue:

```
load 'C:/Users/cpa/data/Ciphertexts.mat'; 
% load 'C:/Users/cpa/data/parsed_cipher_0cm.mat';

% truncate measurements
n_measures = 999;
tab_Obs = tab_Obs(1:n_measures, :);
ciph_dec = double(ciph_dec(1:n_measures, :));  % Force floating point
K = 0:255;
disp(length(K));

Y_i = ciph_dec(:, sbox_n);
F = ones(1, length(K));
sbox_n = 2;

disp(size(Y_i))
disp(size(F))

h1 = (Y_i*ones(1, length(K)));

disp (size(h1))
```